# Can I make a transaction through cluster connection?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-redis, spring-data-commons, spring-data-redis-reactive

I am currently using spring-data-redis-2.7.12.jar version. I want to make a transaction to Redis cluster.
Using multi() on LettuceClusterConnection throws an exception as shown below.

```
@Override
public void multi() {
throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException("MULTI is currently not supported in cluster mode.");
}
```

Could you please tell me why it is not supported?
Can you recommend another good alternative?

[The most recent version, 3.2.1](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-redis/#learn)
 also does not support multi() in cluster connection.

Would changing to Lua scripting or using Redisson be a good alternative?